# how to call function after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

```
$(function() {
    $('#show').avgrund({
        height: 200,
        holderClass: 'custom',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'close',
        onBlurContainer: '.container',
        template:'<div>' +
        '<img src="14.jpg" width="100%"  />' +
        '</div>'
    });
});
```

when click #show button then the function executes but i want to execute the function after page load without clicking any button.
show pop up image before entering into page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#show').avgrund({
        height: 200,
        holderClass: 'custom',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'close',
        onBlurContainer: '.container',
        template: '<div>' +
            '<img src="14.jpg" width="100%"  />' +
            '</div>'
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you are saying, you want to show a div before actually showing other content,

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#div_you_want_to_show').show();
        return false;
    });
```

This will open up before the page the rest of your page is loaded.  If, however you want to show the div after page load, but before the others:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#divs_you_want_to_hide').hide();
        return false;
});

function init() {
    // thing you want to do here
    $("#divs_you_want_to_hide").show();
}

init();
```